# Conditional probability problem-Special Mathematics-Discrete probabilities

Tags: probability

In studying the causes of power failures, the following data have been gathered:10% are due to a transformer damage, 75% are due to line damage, 5% involve both problems. Based on these percentages, find the probability that a given power failure involves:
a)  line damage given that there is transformer damage
b)  transformer damage given that there is line damage
c)  transformer damage but not line damage
d)  transformer damage given that there is no line damage
e)  transformer damage or line damage.

Comment: what about the remaining 10%?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. What did you tried? Where and why did you failed in finding an answer? If you provide context to your question, other members will be more interested in helping you.